# ¿Por qué consulta en sqlserver no me devuelve lo solicitado?

Tags: sql-server

```
select valor as 'DENOMINACIÓN', programa as 'PROGRAMA', COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD, SUM(valor) as TOTAL  from IngresoCupones
where  (ProgramaSolicita='12' or programa='12')  and (valor='100' or valor='50' or valor='20')  and (estado='Ingreso Autorizado' or estado='Devolución' or estado='Devolución autorizado')
group by valor, programa
ORDER BY valor DESC

SELECT SUM(valor) as total from IngresoCupones
where fechaIngreso between fechaIngreso and '2021-08-20' and ( ProgramaSolicita='12' or programa='12' ) and (estado='Ingreso autorizado' or estado='Devolución' or estado='Devolución autorizado')

select MIN(codigo) as DEL, MAX(codigo) as AL ,valor as 'DENOMINACIÓN',programa as 'PROGRAMA',COUNT(*) as 'CANTIDAD', SUM(valor) as 'TOTAL' from IngresoCupones
where fechaIngreso between fechaIngreso and '2021-08-20' and (valor='100' or valor='50' or valor='20') and (ProgramaSolicita='12' or programa='12') and (estado='Devolución' or estado='Ingreso Autorizado' or estado='Devolución autorizado')
group by numeroIngreso, valor, programa
order by valor desc
```

Devuelve cupones de combustible.
Pasa que, por ejemplo, si hubo un préstamo de cupón de un cupón a otro, a la hora de devolverlo se ingresa en la columna *ProgramaSolicita* a qué programa se devolvió. Entonces, por ejemplo, si en *programaSolicita* tiene 13, no debería tomarlo en cuenta y no se debería mostrar ese cupón, **pero sí me devuelve el cupón que tenga programa 01, 11, y 13** y yo quiero que me devuelva solo los de *programa* 12 y *programaSolicita* 12.

Comment: Esta condición `( ProgramaSolicita='12' or programa='12' ) `  te puede retornar eventualmente un `ProgramaSolicita=13`  con  `programa=12`. ¿No tendría que ser en todo caso un `and`?

Comment: Tu pregunta necesita datos de prueba y resultados esperados según los datos de prueba. De nada sirve que muestres código que no hace lo que esperas.